# Algorithm of search unique element in array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Which algorithm to use for searching unique element in array?

For example array is:

```
$arr = [
   ["date" => "2015/04/05",
   "country" => "UK",
   "number" => 3],

   ["date" => "2015/04/05",
   "country" => "UK",
   "number" => 3],

   ["date" => "2015/04/05",
    "country" => "UK",
   "number" => 3],

   ["date" => "2015/04/05",
    "country" => "UK",
   "number" => 4],

];
```

So, I need to count how much element with unique `number`?

In result I should get the following structure:

```
["UK" => array("total" => "2")]
```

Where `total` is number of unique `number` in array.

I tried as:

```
$output = [];

foreach ($arr as $k => $value) {

            $output[
                $value[
                    "country"
                ]][$value["date"]][$value["number"]
            ] = true;
        }

        foreach ($output as $k => $v) {

            foreach ($v as $c => $t) {

                $arr[$k][$c] = count($t);
            }
        }
```

But this code looks so awful, with loops. Also I think there is a trivial algorithm to resolve such issues.

Comment: If the code works, maybe this is more suited for code review (?)

Comment: Code works, but I dont like it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its more suitable on another site, for example https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = [
   ["date" => "2015/04/05", "country" => "UK", "number" => 3],
   ["date" => "2015/04/05", "country" => "UK", "number" => 3],
   ["date" => "2015/04/05", "country" => "UK", "number" => 3],
   ["date" => "2015/04/05", "country" => "UK", "number" => 4],
];

$result=array();
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    $result[$value["country"]][$value['number']] = 1;
}

foreach ($result as $country => $a) {
    $answer[$country]['total'] = count($a);
}

print_r($answer);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [UK] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would give you the desired output.

```
$array = [];

foreach (array_unique(array_column($arr, 'country')) as $country) {
    $filter = array_filter($arr, function ($obj) use ($country) { 
           return $obj['country'] == $country; 
    });
    $array[$country] = array("total" => count(array_unique(array_column($filter, 'number'))));
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this hope this will help you out. Here we are using `foreach` `array_unique` and `array_map`  to achieve desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/809740)

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $value)
{
    $result[$value["country"]][] = $value["number"];
}
$result = array_map(function($value){
    return array("total"=>count(array_unique($value)));
}, $result);
print_r($result)
```

Comment: Not actually giving the required answer